# How to configure Eclipse so it adds private fields at the bottom of a Java class?

Tags: java, eclipse

How to configure Eclipse so it adds private fields at the bottom of a Java class?

By default when I select 'create a field..' the field gets added at the top of the class. Can I configure Eclipse so the fields are added at the bottom instead?

Comment: I don't understand the usefulness of this question unless you alone are the one working on this project or everyone in the project has agreed upon this code formatting style.

Comment: I don't think you can at the time of creation, although there might be an option in source formatting or organization. I might be thinking of Jalopy, though. In any case, I just move mine. If you're not ordering by alpha in the outline view uuuu can just drag, or move them manually.

Comment: @user1329572 So assuming one of those conditions, let's work on answering the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Window` > `Preferences`

On the left choose: `Java` > `Appearance` > `Members Sort Order`

On the right select `Fields` and check `Sort members in same category by visibility`.

After that right-click your project and choose `Source` > `Sort members...` to modify the source code. You can configure Eclipse to execute this action automatically on save: go once again to the preferences `Window` > `Preferences` and then `Java` > `Editor` > `Save actions`, and click on `Configure` for additional actions.

Comment: Does that change their physical location in the file, or just in the view in the packager explorer/etc?

Comment: @AndyPryor Cool, nice to see Eclipse improving. Unfortunate setting location since that's not really "appearance", but can't have everything.

Comment: @Adam Still a new field gets added at the top of a file, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Alex After you had set the preferences as indicated by Adam, you have to call the menu "source -> sort members..." to modify the source code. You can configure Eclipse to execute this action automatically on save: go in the preferences "Java -> Editor -> Save actions", and click on "Configure" for additional actions.